# What causes JsonSerializationException in my Blazor application

Tags: json, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server app is throwing some `JsonSerializationException` at some point but I can't figure out what part causes it. I suspect loop references or some property that is not ignored (decorated with `[JsonIgnore]`), but I can't figure out what object / data that is being serialized acutally causes the issue. This is all I have as an error log in the console:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.7\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.7\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.7\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.7\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

So sure something went wrong, but none of the actual printed stack trace concerns my code... And the debugger doesn't stop either, it's just that the output I excpect is not as it should be, most certainly because of this serialization error...

How can I get more information about where exactly the serialization process failed? Is there a way to get the print out of the Json being serialized itself? If so, how can I do this?

PS: I already disabled "Enable Just My Code" in the debugger, that didn't help...!

Comment: Post (some of) the Serialization / Deserialization code. Try to figure out what is in the related code path.

Comment: And since I see an Aggregate excveption, make sure you include all async/await code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : the whole point of my question is not about WHAT is the error, but HOW to spot it...
Anyway, if you want a link, there's a symple with a few explanations here:
https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/290114

Comment: That link requires an account. On SO you should post complete questions. Right now this is not answerable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok I extracted the sample an posted it here:
https://eswys.ch/tmp/sample.zip
Hope it helps - let me know if you need anything more to help out! Cheers!

Comment: No, questions here should last for a long time. Post a [mcve] without external references.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I eventually found the issue using script debugging

Weird that I couldn't find this option anywhere...

[image: How to enable script debugging in VS 2019 Community]